# How to upload Multiple file in Kentico Custom BizForm?

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, kentico

### I have one Form which created as ascx control.Data was saving in biz form successfully. my problem is how to upload file? i dont know which control i'm using right or not for upload file? and how to add file upload submit here rec.SetValue("UploadCV", duUploadCV.InnerAttachmentGUID); you can see below click button code.i have both code ascx and .cs in below. my ascx upload control which i'm using is right or not ? design code is below.  code .cs is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using CMS.Base;
using CMS.DataEngine;
using CMS.DocumentEngine;
using CMS.EmailEngine;
using CMS.EventLog;
using CMS.FormControls;
using CMS.FormEngine;
using CMS.Helpers;
using CMS.Localization;
using CMS.MacroEngine;
using CMS.Membership;
using CMS.PortalControls;
using CMS.PortalEngine;
using CMS.Protection;
using CMS.SiteProvider;
using CMS.WebAnalytics;
using System.Data;
using CMS.GlobalHelper;
using CMS.TreeEngine;
using CMS.CMSHelper;
using CMS.SiteProvider;
using CMS.EmailEngine;
using CMS.EventLog;
using CMS.DataEngine;
using CMS.WebAnalytics;
using CMS.LicenseProvider;
using CMS.PortalEngine;
using CMS.SettingsProvider;
using CMS.IDataConnectionLibrary;

using CMS.OnlineForms;
using CMS.DataEngine;
using CMS.SiteProvider;
using CMS.Helpers;


using CMS.FormEngine;
using CMS.SettingsProvider;
using CMS.DataEngine;
using CMS.GlobalHelper;

using CMS.ExtendedControls;
using CMS.Helpers;
using CMS.UIControls;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
public partial class CMSWebParts_ePortalWebPart_ePortalControl_GraduateProgramApplication : CMSAbstractWebPart
{
    //public static int SaveSignupForm(SignupFormModel model)

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            GetGender();
            GetUniversity();
            GetStudyArea();
            GetSpecializationEng();

        }

    }

    #region "Layout properties"
    public override string SkinID
    {
        get
        {
            return base.SkinID;
        }
        set
        {
            base.SkinID = value;
            SetSkinID(value);
        }
    }
    public string NameText
    {
        get
        {
            return DataHelper.GetNotEmpty(GetValue("NameText"), ResHelper.LocalizeString("{$GPAName$}"));


        }
        set
        {
            SetValue("NameText", value);
            lblName.Text = value;

        }
    }

    #endregion
    public string DOBText
    {
        get
        {
            return DataHelper.GetNotEmpty(GetValue("DOBText"), ResHelper.LocalizeString("{$GPADateOfBirth$}"));

        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue("LastNameText", value);
            lblDOB.Text = value;
        }
    }
    public string EmailText
    {
        get
        {
            return DataHelper.GetNotEmpty(this.GetValue("EmailText"), ResHelper.LocalizeString("{$Webparts_Membership_RegistrationForm.Email$}"));
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue("EmailText", value);
            lblEmail.Text = value;
        }
    }
    public string Submit
    {
        get
        {
            return DataHelper.GetNotEmpty(GetValue("Submit"), ResHelper.LocalizeString("{$custom.custom.Submit$}"));

        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue("Submit", value);
            btnOk.Text = value;
        }
    }
    public string Gender
    {
        get
        {
            return DataHelper.GetNotEmpty(GetValue("Gender"), ResHelper.LocalizeString("{$GPAGender$}"));

        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue("Gender", value);
            lblGender.Text = value;
        }
    }
    public string Email
    {
        get
        {
            return DataHelper.GetNotEmpty(GetValue("Email"), ResHelper.LocalizeString("{$GPAEmail$}"));

        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue("Email", value);
            lblEmail.Text = value;
        }
    }
    public string GSMNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return DataHelper.GetNotEmpty(GetValue("GSMNumber"), ResHelper.LocalizeString("{$GPAGSMNumber$}"));

        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue("GSMNumber", value);
            lblGSMNumber.Text = value;
        }
    }
    public string Grade
    {
        get
        {
            return DataHelper.GetNotEmpty(GetValue("Grade"), ResHelper.LocalizeString("{$GPAGrade$}"));

        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue("Grade", value);
            lblGrade.Text = value;
        }
    }
    public string ExpectGraduateDate
    {
        get
        {
            return DataHelper.GetNotEmpty(GetValue("ExpectGraduateDate"), ResHelper.LocalizeString("{$GPAExpectGraduateDate$}"));

        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue("ExpectGraduateDate", value);
            lblExpectGraduateDate.Text = value;
        }
    }
    public string University
    {
        get
        {
            return DataHelper.GetNotEmpty(GetValue("University"), ResHelper.LocalizeString("{$GPAUniversity$}"));

        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue("University", value);
            lblUniversity.Text = value;
        }
    }
    public string StudyArea
    {
        get
        {
            return DataHelper.GetNotEmpty(GetValue("StudyArea"), ResHelper.LocalizeString("{$GPAStudyArea$}"));

        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue("StudyArea", value);
            lblStudyArea.Text = value;
        }
    }
    public string Specialization
    {
        get
        {
            return DataHelper.GetNotEmpty(GetValue("Specialization"), ResHelper.LocalizeString("{$GPASpecialization$}"));

        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue("Specialization", value);
            lblSpecialization.Text = value;
        }
    }
    public string WhyJoinPAEW
    {
        get
        {
            return DataHelper.GetNotEmpty(GetValue("WhyJoinPAEW"), ResHelper.LocalizeString("{$GPAWhyJoinPAEW$}"));

        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue("WhyJoinPAEW", value);
            lblWhyJoinPAEW.Text = value;
        }
    }
    public string UploadCV
    {
        get
        {
            return DataHelper.GetNotEmpty(GetValue("UploadCV"), ResHelper.LocalizeString("{$GPAUploadCV$}"));

        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue("UploadCV", value);
            lblUploadCV.Text = value;
        }
    }
    public string Certificates
    {
        get
        {
            return DataHelper.GetNotEmpty(GetValue("Certificates"), ResHelper.LocalizeString("{$GPACertificates$}"));

        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue("Certificates", value);
            lblCertificates.Text = value;
        }
    }

    protected void SetupControl()
    {
        if (this.StopProcessing)
        {
            // Do not process
            rfvName.Enabled = false;
            rfvDOB.Enabled = false;
            rfvEmail.Enabled = false;
            revEmail.Enabled = false;
            rfvGSMNumber.Enabled = false;
            revMobile.Enabled = false;
            rvGrade.Enabled = false;
            rfvGrade.Enabled = false;
            rvExpectGraduateDate.Enabled = false;
            rfvExpectGraduateDate.Enabled = false;
            rfvUniversity.Enabled = false;
            rfvWhyJoinPAEW.Enabled = false;
           // rfvUploadCV.Enabled = false;
           // rfvCertificates.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            // Set texts
            lblName.Text = this.NameText;
            lblDOB.Text = this.DOBText;
            btnOk.Text = this.Submit;
            lblGender.Text = this.Gender;
            lblEmail.Text = this.Email;
            lblGSMNumber.Text = this.GSMNumber;
            lblGrade.Text = this.Grade;
            lblExpectGraduateDate.Text = this.ExpectGraduateDate;
            lblUniversity.Text = this.University;
            lblStudyArea.Text = this.StudyArea;
            lblSpecialization.Text = this.Specialization;
            lblWhyJoinPAEW.Text = this.WhyJoinPAEW;
            lblUploadCV.Text = this.UploadCV;
            lblCertificates.Text = this.Certificates;
            //lddSpecialization.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(ResHelper.GetString(ResHelper.LocalizeString("{$GPASpecialization$}"),CultureHelper.GetPreferredCulture())));
           // BizForm1.OnAfterSave += new BizForm.OnAfterSaveEventHandler(GetGender());
           // ObjectEvents.Insert.After += new EventHandler<ObjectEventArgs>(Insert_After);


            // Set required field validators texts
            rfvName.ErrorMessage = ResHelper.GetString("GPArfv");
            rfvDOB.ErrorMessage = ResHelper.GetString("GPArfv");
            rfvEmail.ErrorMessage = ResHelper.GetString("GPArfv");
            revEmail.ErrorMessage = ResHelper.GetString("GPArfv");
            rfvGSMNumber.ErrorMessage = ResHelper.GetString("GPArfv");
            revMobile.ErrorMessage = ResHelper.GetString("GPArevMobile");
            rvGrade.ErrorMessage = ResHelper.GetString("GPAGradeLess");
            rfvGrade.ErrorMessage = ResHelper.GetString("GPArfv");
            rvExpectGraduateDate.ErrorMessage = ResHelper.GetString("GPArvExpectGraduateDate");
            rfvExpectGraduateDate.ErrorMessage = ResHelper.GetString("GPArfv");
            rfvUniversity.ErrorMessage = ResHelper.GetString("GPArfv");
            rfvWhyJoinPAEW.ErrorMessage = ResHelper.GetString("GPArfv");
           // rfvUploadCV.ErrorMessage = ResHelper.GetString("Webparts_Membership_RegistrationForm.rfvLastName");
          //  rfvCertificates.ErrorMessage = ResHelper.GetString("Webparts_Membership_RegistrationForm.rfvLastName");
            // Set SkinID
            if (!this.StandAlone && (this.PageCycle < PageCycleEnum.Initialized))
            {
                SetSkinID(this.SkinID);
            }


        }
    }

    void SetSkinID(string skinId)
    {
        if (skinId != "")
        {
            lblName.SkinID = skinId;
            lblDOB.SkinID = skinId;

        }
    }

    public override void OnContentLoaded()
    {
        base.OnContentLoaded();
        SetupControl();

    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Reloads data
    /// </summary>
    public override void ReloadData()
    {
        base.ReloadData();
        SetupControl();
    }

         /////////////////// Append Gender Radio List ///////////////////
    private void GetGender()
    {
            Dictionary<string, string> Genderdic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            Genderdic.Add("1", "Male"); Genderdic.Add("2", "Female");
            rvGender.DataSource = Genderdic;
            rvGender.DataValueField = "Key";
            rvGender.DataTextField = "Value";
            rvGender.DataBind();
            rvGender.SelectedValue = "1";
      }
           /////////////////// Append Gender Radio List ///////////////////
            private void GetUniversity()
            {
            Dictionary<string, string> Universitydic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            Universitydic.Add("1", "Sultan Qaboos University"); Universitydic.Add("2", "Higher College of Technology"); Universitydic.Add("3", "Other");
            ddlUniversity.DataSource = Universitydic;
            ddlUniversity.DataValueField = "Key";
            ddlUniversity.DataTextField = "Value";
            ddlUniversity.DataBind();
            }

            private void GetStudyArea()
            {
                Dictionary<string, string> StudyAreadic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                StudyAreadic.Add("1", "Engineering"); StudyAreadic.Add("2", "Business");
                rblStudyArea.DataSource = StudyAreadic;
                rblStudyArea.DataValueField = "Key";
                rblStudyArea.DataTextField = "Value";
                rblStudyArea.DataBind();
                rblStudyArea.SelectedValue = "1";
            }
            private void GetSpecializationEng()
            {
                Dictionary<string, string> Specializationdic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                if (rblStudyArea.SelectedValue == "1")
                {
                Specializationdic.Add("1", "Mechanical"); Specializationdic.Add("2", "Instrumentation"); Specializationdic.Add("3", "Civil"); Specializationdic.Add("4", "Chemistry"); Specializationdic.Add("5", "Water Resources"); Specializationdic.Add("6", "Other");
                }
                else
                { 
                    Specializationdic.Add("1", "Finance"); Specializationdic.Add("2", "HR"); Specializationdic.Add("3", "Communication"); Specializationdic.Add("4", "BA"); Specializationdic.Add("5", "Other");
                }
                lddSpecialization.DataSource = Specializationdic;
                lddSpecialization.DataValueField = "Key";
                lddSpecialization.DataTextField = "Value";
                lddSpecialization.DataBind();
                lddSpecialization.SelectedValue = "1";
            }
            protected void ddlUniversity_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (ddlUniversity.SelectedValue == "3")
                { txtUniversity.Visible = true;}
                else
                { txtUniversity.Visible = false;}

            }
            protected void rblStudyArea_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                GetSpecializationEng();
            }
            protected void lddSpecialization_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (rblStudyArea.SelectedValue == "1")
                {
                    if (lddSpecialization.SelectedValue == "6")
                    { txtSpecialization.Visible = true; }
                    else
                    { txtSpecialization.Visible = false; }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (lddSpecialization.SelectedValue == "5")
                    { txtSpecialization.Visible = true; }
                    else
                    { txtSpecialization.Visible = false; }

                }
            }
           protected void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                    if ((this.PageManager.ViewMode == ViewModeEnum.Design) || (this.HideOnCurrentPage) || (!this.IsVisible))
                    {
                        // Do not process
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rfvName.Validate();
                        rfvDOB.Validate();
                        rfvEmail.Validate();
                        revEmail.Validate();
                        rfvGSMNumber.Validate();
                        revMobile.Validate();
                        rvGrade.Validate();
                        rfvGrade.Validate();
                        rvExpectGraduateDate.Validate();
                        rfvExpectGraduateDate.Validate();
                        rfvUniversity.Validate();
                        rfvWhyJoinPAEW.Validate();
                        Page.Validate();
                        //if (Page.IsValid)
                        //{
                        String siteName = SiteContext.CurrentSiteName;


                        #region "Banned IPs"

                        // Ban IP addresses which are blocked for registration
                        if (!BannedIPInfoProvider.IsAllowed(siteName, BanControlEnum.Registration))
                        {
                            lblError.Visible = true;
                            lblError.Text = GetString("banip.ipisbannedregistration");
                            return;
                        }

                        #endregion

                        BizFormInfo formObject = BizFormInfoProvider.GetBizFormInfo("GraduateProgramApplication", SiteContext.CurrentSiteID);
                        if (formObject != null)
                        {
                            DataClassInfo formClass = DataClassInfoProvider.GetDataClassInfo(formObject.FormClassID);
                            if (formClass != null)
                            {
                                BizFormItemProvider bProvider = new BizFormItemProvider();
                                BizFormItem rec = BizFormItem.New(formClass.ClassName, null);
                                DateTime Applicant_DOB = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDOB.Text.Trim(), "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
                                DateTime Applicant_ExpectGraduateDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtExpectGraduateDate.Text.Trim(), "MM/dd/yyyy", null);
                                rec.SetValue("FullName", txtName.Text.Trim());
                                rec.SetValue("DOB", Applicant_DOB);
                                rec.SetValue("Gender", rvGender.SelectedItem.Text.Trim());
                                rec.SetValue("Email", txtEmail.Text.Trim());
                                rec.SetValue("GSMNumber", txtGSMNumber.Text.Trim());
                                rec.SetValue("Grade", txtGrade.Text.Trim());
                                rec.SetValue("ExpectGraduateDate", Applicant_ExpectGraduateDate);
                                rec.SetValue("University", ddlUniversity.SelectedItem.Text.Trim());
                                rec.SetValue("StudyArea", rblStudyArea.SelectedItem.Text.Trim());
                                rec.SetValue("Specialization", lddSpecialization.SelectedItem.Text.Trim());
                                rec.SetValue("WhyPAEW", txtWhyJoinPAEW.Text.Trim());
                                // rec.SetValue("UploadCV", duUploadCV.InnerAttachmentGUID);

                                // BasicForm.Data.GetValue("answerText"), "");
                                rec.SetValue("FormInserted", DateTime.Now);
                                rec.SetValue("FormUpdated", DateTime.Now);
                                rec.Insert();
                                BizFormInfoProvider.RefreshDataCount(formObject.FormName, formObject.FormSiteID);

                            }

                        }
                        string test = "Hello";
                        Response.Write("<script>alert('" + test + "');</script>");
                    }

            }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to trigger the direct uploader to save the file somehow, before it will give you a GUID - I'm not completely familiar with how it works because I've never used it outside of the context of the Kentico form engine.

That being said, I think that the Forms module in Kentico would do everything that I can see you're trying to do here without you needing to write custom code.

Whenever I create a form in Kentico I try to leverage the forms module as much as possible.

I would recommend reading through the documentation for the forms module for whichever version of Kentico you're using to try create the form through the User Interface, and then asking questions if you get stuck on something through that process - unless there's something custom that I've misunderstood.